# Why does a Perl background process require an ENTER keystroke on Windows 2012?

Tags: windows, perl, amazon-web-services

On my Amazon Web Services (AWS) Windows 2012 systems, a Perl script that runs in the background listening for network requests requires an ENTER keystroke in the server script (background proc) cmd window before the backticks return. This does not happen on my non-AWS Windows 2008 R2 systems (the proc runs properly with no interaction). It also works properly (no interaction required) on my AWS Linux systems.

My question is, is whether this is a Windows 2012 issue or an AWS issue, as I don't have any 2k12 servers to test on that aren't in AWS. I'd appreciate if anyone with 2k12 systems could test this to see if it works properly.

To repro:

```
- copy below code to client.pl and server.pl respectively
- start the server in the background: 
    perl server.pl bg

- run the client (different cmd window):
    perl client.pl
```

On my local servers, the server returns to the client properly without any interaction. On my AWS systems, it hangs. Hitting ENTER in the server cmd window causes backticks to return and the response to be sent across. Running the server script in foreground mode `perl server.pl run`, the whole shebang works properly on 2012 with no interaction.

NOTE: there's no method in this test code to stop the `server.pl` background proc. It has to be killed via Task Manager. Also, the test scripts require no non-core modules (at least with Strawberry Perl).

client.pl:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use IO::Socket::INET;
use Storable;

my $mod = 'IO::Socket::INET';

my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
    PeerHost => 'localhost',
    PeerPort => 7800,
    Proto => 'tcp',
);
die "can't create socket\n" unless $sock;

$sock->send("cpanm $mod");

my $recv = Storable::fd_retrieve($sock);

print $$recv;
```

server.pl

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use IO::Socket::INET;
use Storable;

if (@ARGV && $ARGV[0] eq 'bg'){
    system 1, 'perl', $0, 'run';
}
if (@ARGV && $ARGV[0] eq 'run') {
    my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
        LocalHost => '0.0.0.0',
        LocalPort => 7800,
        Proto => 'tcp',
        Listen => 5,
        Reuse => 1,
    );
    die "cannot create socket $!\n" unless $sock;

    while (1){
        my $conn = $sock->accept;

        my $cmd;
        $conn->recv($cmd, 1024);

        print "executing: $cmd\n";
        my $ret = `$cmd`;
        print "return: $ret\n";
        Storable::nstore_fd(\$ret, $conn);

        shutdown($conn, 1);
    }

    $sock->close;
}
```

Comment: @ikegami: I meant "don't require any non-core modules". I'll give your suggestion a try here shortly. Currently AFK

Comment: @ikegami: both variants of your `perl` strings hang the same as the `cpanm` call

Comment: @ikegami: the server script cmd window requires an ENTER keystroke before the `cpanm` command returns anything. The perl proc that is handling it fires, but does nothing until a keystroke

Comment: @ikegami: yes, the server doesn't respond to client until keystroke in the server window

Comment: because I have two cmd windows open...

Comment: @ikegami: the server script outputs "executing: ...", but until I hit ENTER, the return from the cpanm command isn't returned. I haven't thoroughly tested whether the `qx` code is actually processed before or after I hit ENTER though. I've got to run for a little bit, but I'll be back at it when I return. Thanks for your suggestions/questions thus far

Comment: @ikegami: no, I don't